# How can I keep a newly created tab from being closed?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a tab and make it always visible. So I crated an extension, and set the popup html to a page containing the following script,

manifest:

```
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "popup": "popup.html"
   },
```

The script to include in the popup.html:

```
chrome.tabs.create({
url: chrome.extension.getURL('htdocs/index.html'),
active: false,
pinned: true
});
```

So each time my browser starts, I got a new tab created. But when I accidentally closed it, I can't re-open it anymore.

Any ideas on how to keep the tab from being closed? Or how to open the tab again when I click on the button?

Comment: Don't try to force the tab to be opened, that's annoying. Take a look at [`chrome.browserAction.onClicked`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked). Bind an event listener which runs the code you've written in the question.

Comment: @RobW Wow Thanks, you definitely should put that as an answer. I've modified the button to create a new page ;-)